# Images only showing in firefox

Tags: wordpress

I have modified the header.php to pull in an image instead of icons on my blog hoesbeforedoughs.co.uk, however the image only shows in firefox, it currently does not show in ie, chrome or safari.

Any ideas?

```
<div id ="icons"> 
    <?php if ( $bavotasan_theme_options['header_icon'] ) { ?> 
        <img src='http://hoesbeforedoughs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icons-01.png'></img>
    <?php } else { 
        $space_class = ' class="margin-top"'; 
    } ?> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant bit of code?

Comment: Whoops sorry, 

<div id ="icons">
         <?php if ( $bavotasan_theme_options['header_icon'] ) { ?>
         <img src='http://hoesbeforedoughs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icons-01.png'></img>
         <?php } else {
          $space_class = ' class="margin-top"';
         } ?>
</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your image http://hoesbeforedoughs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icons-01.png  does not exist anymore. Your Firefox browser cached it and that is why you are seeing it on firefox. Reupload the image to the correct folder with same name. Clear browsers cache. You will see it on all browser.

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening your website in Firefox and the image is not found.
This could be a result of uploading images with the same name (or the same image multiple times). Wordpress automatically renames images with the same name. Perhaps you accidentally removed the duplicate with this url. If the image is still shown (especially if it's only for one browser) it may be cached. If you delete your cache I doubt you will still see the image. 
To solve this, go to the "media" section of the admin area and check if the image is still there. If so, click on it and take the exact url for the image and put it as the source for your image in the php file.